# Why can't I solve a system of four third-order partial differential equations using NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, finite-element-method

I solve the problem of optimal control. First, I solve a system of two equations (with respect to the variables p, q, V, n) with already optimal conditions (Kopt and Sopt) to check whether it is possible to solve such a system at all. It turns out that everything is OK, but the non-linear part of the equation cannot be discarded, it is important. I am using the NDSolve function with the StiffnessSwitching specification:

```
Kopt[t_] := 
  6.03626835*10^17*t^7 - 4.51848425*10^16 *t^6 + 
   1.36700872*10^15*t^5 - 2.13240902*10^13*t^4 + 
   1.80975334*10^11*t^3 - 7.99509911*10^8*t^2 +  
   1.51825005*10^6 *t^1 + 1.87782986*t^0;

Sopt[t_] := 
  0. - 90989.2 t + 1.39914*10^9 t^2 - 8.76585*10^12 t^3 + 
 2.99045*10^16 t^4 - 6.32825*10^19 t^5 + 9.0249*10^22 t^6 - 
 9.14249*10^25 t^7 + 6.81239*10^28 t^8 - 3.82682*10^31 t^9 + 
 1.65063*10^34 t^10 - 5.54261*10^36 t^11 + 1.46314*10^39 t^12 - 
 3.0549*10^41 t^13 + 5.05619*10^43 t^14 - 6.62179*10^45 t^15 + 
 6.81692*10^47 t^16 - 5.44703*10^49 t^17 + 3.30728*10^51 t^18 - 
 1.47379*10^53 t^19 + 4.54318*10^54 t^20 - 8.65281*10^55 t^21 + 
 7.66886*10^56 t^22;



eq1 = D[n[x, t], t] + D[n[x, t]*V[x, t], x] == 0;
eq2 = D[V[x, t], t] + Kopt[t]*x - 
    2*(2*250^2)*Sopt[t]*Sin[k*x]*Cos[k*x]*k + V[x, t]*D[V[x, t], x] + 
    g*D[n[x, t], x] - 
    D[ D[Sqrt[n[x, t]], x, x]/(2*Sqrt[n[x, t]]), x] == 0;

eqo1 = D[n[x, t], t] + D[n[x, t]*V[x, t], x] == 0;
eqo2nl = D[V[x, t], t] + Kopt[t]*x - 
    8*(2*250^2)*Sopt[t]*Sin[k*x]*Cos[k*x]*k + V[x, t]*D[V[x, t], x] + 
    g*D[n[x, t], 
      x] - ((D[n[x, t], x])^3 - 
       2*n[x, t]*D[n[x, t], x]*D[n[x, t], {x, 2}] + 
       D[n[x, t], {x, 3}]*(n[x, t])^2)/(4*(n[x, t])^3) == 0;




cond1 = n[x, t] == ((Sqrt[Kzero]/Pi)^(1/2))*
     Exp[-0.5*Sqrt[Kzero]*x^2] /. t -> 0;
cond2 =  n[x, t] == 0. /. x -> -10;
cond3 =  n[x, t] == 0. /. x -> 10;

cond4 = V[x, t] == 0. /. t -> 0;
cond5 = V[x, t] == 0. /. x -> -10;
cond6 = V[x, t] == 0. /. x -> 10;


sol5 = NDSolve[{eqo1, eqo2nl, cond1, cond2, cond3, cond4, cond5, 
    cond6}, {V, n}, {x, -10, 10}, {t, 0, Tv}, 
   Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", 
     Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", Automatic}}, AccuracyGoal -> 1, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 1];
```

Next, I solve four equations in order to find the control parameter K (depends on q), while Sopt is still known. The initial conditions are the same and as banal as possible. Add two more equations and K[t] formula:

```
K[t_] := -1*Integrate[q[x, t]*x^2, {x, -10, 10}];

eqo3 = D[q[x, t], t] == - n[x, t]*D[p[x, t], x]  - 
    V[x, t]*D[q[x, t], x];

eqo4 = D[p[x, t], t] +  D[p[x, t], x]*V[x, t] + g*D[q[x, t], x] == 0;
```

The linearized system has a solution, but not a nonlinear one! There are many problems, including the order of the equation:

```
The spatial derivative order of the PDE may not exceed two.
```

I try to remove the third order derivative from the nonlinear part:

```
The maximum derivative order of the nonlinear PDE coefficients for \
the Finite Element Method is larger than 1. It may help to rewrite \
the PDE in inactive form.
```

Why does he even use only FEM now? Why was a nonlinear system of two equations solved normally?

Comment: Parameters `k, g, Tv, Kzero, Sopt, Kopt` not defined.

Comment: k = (20.3/589)*10^3, g = 1039, Kzero  = 10. Kopt and Sopt are interpolation polynomials. But they do not bring the main problem.

Comment: Add to your post this data including functions  `Kopt, Sopt`.

Comment: Did it, thanks.

Comment: Ok! What is there `Tv`?

Comment: That is integration time limit: Tv = 3.9*10^(-6)

Comment: What system of equations did you solve and with what conditions in the second case? Note that you cannot use the character `K` (system symbol), use, for instance `Knopt[t_] := -Integrate[q[x, t]*x^2, {x, -10, 10}];`

Comment: Here is a system:

eqo1 = D[n[x, t], t] + D[n[x, t]*V[x, t], x] == 0;


eqo2 =    
  D[V[x, t], t] + K[t]*x - 
    0.1*(2*250^2)*Sopt[t]*Sin[k*x]*Cos[k*x]*k + 
    V[x, t]*D[V[x, t], x] + g*D[n[x, t], x] == 0;

eqo3 = D[q[x, t], t] == - n[x, t]*D[p[x, t], x]  - 
    V[x, t]*D[q[x, t], x];
eqo4 = D[p[x, t], t] +  D[p[x, t], x]*V[x, t] + g*D[q[x, t], x] == 0;

Comment: With conditions:
c1 = n[x, t] == ((Sqrt[Kzero]/Pi)^(1/2))*Exp[-Sqrt[Kzero]*x^2] /. 
   t -> 0;
c2 =  n[x, t] == 0. /. x -> x0;
c3 =  n[x, t] == 0. /. x -> xf;
c4 = V[x, t] == 0. /. t -> 0;
c5 = V[x, t] == 0. /. x -> x0;
c6 = V[x, t] == 0. /. x -> xf;
c7 =  p[x, t] == 0 /. t -> Tv;
c10 = q[x, t] == 0 /. t -> Tv;

Comment: You cannot set boundary conditions like `c7 = p[x, t] == 0 /. t -> Tv; c10 = q[x, t] == 0 /. t -> Tv`. You can set the initial data `c7 = p[x, t] == 0 /. t -> 0; c10 = q[x, t] == 0 /. t ->0`. With these conditions, I got a solution.

Comment: You should add all parameters to the post, otherwise it is unlikely that people can/will help you.

Answer (score 3):

We use `Knopt[t]` instead of `K[t]` (K is a system symbol) and initial data `p[x, 0] == Cos[Pi x/20], q[x, 0] == 0` instead of `c7 = p[x, t] == 0 /. t -> Tv; c10 = q[x, t] == 0 /. t -> Tv`. Then the numerical solution converges:

```
Sopt[t_] := 
  0. - 90989.2 t + 1.39914*10^9 t^2 - 8.76585*10^12 t^3 + 
   2.99045*10^16 t^4 - 6.32825*10^19 t^5 + 9.0249*10^22 t^6 - 
   9.14249*10^25 t^7 + 6.81239*10^28 t^8 - 3.82682*10^31 t^9 + 
   1.65063*10^34 t^10 - 5.54261*10^36 t^11 + 1.46314*10^39 t^12 - 
   3.0549*10^41 t^13 + 5.05619*10^43 t^14 - 6.62179*10^45 t^15 + 
   6.81692*10^47 t^16 - 5.44703*10^49 t^17 + 3.30728*10^51 t^18 - 
   1.47379*10^53 t^19 + 4.54318*10^54 t^20 - 8.65281*10^55 t^21 + 
   7.66886*10^56 t^22;
Knopt[t_] := -Integrate[q[x, t]*x^2, {x, -10, 10}];
k = (20.3/589)*10^3; g = 1039; Kzero = 10.; Tv = 3.9*10^(-6);
eq1 = D[n[x, t], t] + D[n[x, t]*V[x, t], x] == 0;
eq2 = D[V[x, t], t] + Kopt[t]*x - 
    2*(2*250^2)*Sopt[t] Sin[k*x]*Cos[k*x]*k + V[x, t]*D[V[x, t], x] + 
    g*D[n[x, t], x] - 
    D[D[Sqrt[n[x, t]], x, x]/(2*Sqrt[n[x, t]]), x] == 0;

eqo1 = D[n[x, t], t] + D[n[x, t]*V[x, t], x] == 0;
eqo2nl = D[V[x, t], t] + Kopt[t]*x - 
    8*(2*250^2)*Sopt[t]*Sin[k*x]*Cos[k*x]*k + V[x, t]*D[V[x, t], x] + 
    g*D[n[x, t], 
      x] - ((D[n[x, t], x])^3 - 
       2*n[x, t]*D[n[x, t], x]*D[n[x, t], {x, 2}] + 
       D[n[x, t], {x, 3}]*(n[x, t])^2)/(4*(n[x, t])^3) == 0;

cond1 = n[x, t] == ((Sqrt[Kzero]/Pi)^(1/2))*
     Exp[-0.5*Sqrt[Kzero]*x^2] /. t -> 0;
cond2 = n[x, t] == 0. /. x -> -10;
cond3 = n[x, t] == 0. /. x -> 10;

cond4 = V[x, t] == 0. /. t -> 0;
cond5 = V[x, t] == 0. /. x -> -10;
cond6 = V[x, t] == 0. /. x -> 10;


eqo3 = D[q[x, t], t] == -n[x, t]*D[p[x, t], x] - V[x, t]*D[q[x, t], x];

eqo4 = D[p[x, t], t] + D[p[x, t], x]*V[x, t] + g*D[q[x, t], x] == 
  0; eqo2n2 = 
 D[V[x, t], t] + Knopt[t]*x - 
   8*(2*250^2)*Sopt[t]*Sin[k*x]*Cos[k*x]*k + V[x, t]*D[V[x, t], x] + 
   g*D[n[x, t], 
     x] - ((D[n[x, t], x])^3 - 
      2*n[x, t]*D[n[x, t], x]*D[n[x, t], {x, 2}] + 
      D[n[x, t], {x, 3}]*(n[x, t])^2)/(4*(n[x, t])^3) == 0;

ic = {n[x, 0] == ((Sqrt[Kzero]/Pi)^(1/2))*Exp[-0.5*Sqrt[Kzero]*x^2], 
   V[x, 0] == 0, p[x, 0] == Cos[Pi x/20], q[x, 0] == 0};
bc = {cond2, cond3, cond5, cond6, p[-10, t] == 0, p[10, t] == 0, 
   q[-10, t] == 0, q[10, t] == 0};

sol5 = NDSolve[{eqo1, eqo2n2, eqo3, eqo4, ic, bc}, {V, n, p, 
    q}, {x, -10, 10}, {t, 0, Tv}];
{DensityPlot[V[x, t] /. sol5, {x, -10, 10}, {t, 0, Tv}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> "V"],
 DensityPlot[n[x, t] /. sol5, {x, -10, 10}, {t, 0, Tv}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "n"], 
 DensityPlot[p[x, t] /. sol5, {x, -10, 10}, {t, 0, Tv}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> "p"],
 DensityPlot[q[x, t] /. sol5, {x, -10, 10}, {t, 0, Tv}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "q"]}
```

[image: Figure 1]